# C# Windows Forms: OpenFileDialog Strange Issues

Tags: c#, winforms

This is kinda strange, let me try to explain it as best as possible:

When I create a new file and Save it, it saves correctly (test.xml).
When I make changes to this file and Save it, it saves correctly (to test.xml)
When I make changes again to this file or just choose Save As, it works correctly (newtest.xml)

However, when I do a file open, make changes to a file (test.xml) and click Save it is saving to (newtest.xml).

This is in my MainForm.cs

```
            if (this.openEditorDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK && editForm != null)
        {


            editForm.Close();                
            editForm = new EditorForm(this);
            editForm.OpenFile(this.openEditorDialog1.FileName);
            editForm.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(EditorForm_Closing);
            editForm.MdiParent = this;
            editForm.Show();
        }

private void biFileSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!editForm.HasFileName)
            {
                if (this.saveEditorDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog1.FileName);
                    editForm.FileName = this.saveEditorDialog1.FileName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog1.FileName);
            }
```

This is in my EditorForm.cs

```
  public void OpenFile(string strFileName)
    {

        diagramComponent.LoadSoap(mainForm.openEditorDialog1.FileName);
        this.FileName = mainForm.openEditorDialog1.FileName;
        this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = DiagramTab;

    }
```

I'm sure it has to do with the what I'm doing in the EditoForm but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else
{
    this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog1.FileName);
```

It looks like you want:

```
    this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(editForm.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

It must have to do with `mainForm.openEditorDialog1.FileName`.  Use a `FileName` property of the form that does the saving.  When you open the file, set the fileName to `mainForm.openEditorDialog1.FileName`.  When you SaveAs, set the `FileName` property there, too.  This way, whenever the current file, changes you set the FileName property appropriately.  Then, when it comes time to save the file, you always have the correct filename.

In summary, only use the `.FileName` property of the SaveAs dialog or the FileOpen dialog right after you use them.

Comment: Hmmm...I think you are right. Although, I'm trying to do that (added my save method above). How do I call the correct FileName from my MainForm?

Comment: You can put a property on EditorForm for the filename.  Then when you are done with EditorForm (or whenever you need the name), get editorForm.FileName.